# returning address of local variable is bad THEN why this code works

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Returning the address of a variable inside a function is bad because that variable will no longer exist
if the stack frame where the variable belongs end.

So why this code works fine

```
int* test(){
    int a = 11;
    return &a;
}

int main(){

    int *a;
    a = test();

    cout << *a;

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 5):

> So why this code works fine

Undefined behaviour means the code can *appear* to work fine. But it's still undefined.

In your case, `a` is a dangling pointer.

Comment: so I should avoid doing this?

Comment: @user1393669 not only avoid. You should explicitly not do this.

Comment: @user1393669 Undefined behavior is compiler/machine specific. It may work fine on your machine, but it may crash on someone else's.

Comment: Yes.  Avoiding *undefined behavior* is always a good thing.  Programs like defined behavior a lot better and produces as many bugs / defects.

Comment: dangling pointer points to random memory address right? so why when I compile the output is still 11

Comment: @user1393669: Basically, you're using the variable before the computer happens to get around to cleaning it up. There is absolutely no guarantee that it won't clean it up before you use it, you're just currently getting "lucky" in your exact test case.

Answer (score 0):

The code is still wrong. It may *appear* to work now, but won't next week. It may appear to work now, but change one small thing and it no longer "works".

Try this. Add another function, `test2`:

```
int *test()
{
    int a = 11;
    return &a;
}

int test2()
{
    int b = 13;
}

int main()
{
    int *a;

    a = test();
    cout << "after test: " << *a << endl;

    test2();
    cout << "after test2: " << *a << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Now is `11` printed both times? Note that it *could* still print `11` twice, but it probably won't. We are, after all, still flirting with undefined behavior here.

But on my machine, I see:

```
after test: 11
after test2: 13
```

`test2` has clobbered the space on the stack that my dangling pointer was pointing to. The code is incorrect. The variable defined inside the function `test` is out of scope when the function exits, and is no longer valid. Maintaining a reference to it doesn't change this.